# Uniqueness unitization of a non unital $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am trying to show that the unitization of a non-unital AF $C^*$-algebra, $A$ , is again an AF $C^*$-algebra. 
In order to do so, I tried to claim the following:

> Let $A, B$ be $C^*$ algebras and suppose that $A$ is an ideal in $B$ and $B/A$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$. 
>   In these conditions, is it true that $B$ and $A^+$ (the unitization of $A$) are isomorphic as $C^*$ algebras?

**Edit:** I think I should require $B$ to be with multiplicative unit.

Comment: I have edited to change "unitalization" to "unitization", which I think is the more standard term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $A$ is not unital, we have that $A^+=A\oplus\mathbb C$ with the product $$(a_1,\lambda_1)(a_2,\lambda_2)=(a_1a_2+\lambda_2a_1+\lambda_1a_2,\lambda_1\lambda_2).$$
 Consider the map $\phi:A^+\to B$ given by
$$
\phi(a,\lambda)=a+\lambda I.
$$
 This is clearly a $*$-homomorphism. Since $A$ is non-unital, this map is one-to-one. So it remains to check it is onto. Given $b\in B$, we have $b+A=\lambda(b)+A$ for some  $\lambda(b)\in\mathbb C$, so there exists $a\in A$ such that $b=\lambda I+a=\phi(a,\lambda(b))$.

Comment: Thank you Martin! clear as always :)

Comment: In the counterexample you gave, $A=\Bbb{C}\oplus 0$ is a unital $C^*$ algebra. So, its unitization will be isomorphic to the $C^*$ algebra $A\oplus \Bbb{C}$, which I think isomorphic to $B=\Bbb{C}^2$, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The "counterexample" is not such.

Answer (score 3):

The unitization is a left adjoint functor (to the inclusion functor).

As such the unitization commutes with *arbitrary colimits*.

AF-algebras are colimits of finite dimensional C*-algebras.

The unitization of finite dimensional C*-algebras are finite dimensional.

So the unitization of AF-algebras are AF-algebras.